# syntax error near unexpected token `newline' on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am getting this error

install-logging-agent.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' install-logging-agent.sh: line 2:` '

on this command
curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/install-logging-agent.sh
sudo bash install-logging-agent.sh

Comment: Have you seen these instructions for installing the logging agent?  https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/installation

Comment: Execute the two commands **one at a time** and not as a single command.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same installation script for a server I set up back in 2018 and ran into the same issue today. The installation method we are using appears to have been deprecated by Google because trying to load the URL https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/install-logging-agent.sh returns a 404 error. This was still working for me two weeks ago, so it was something recent.

The solution would be to update your installation method to follow the current documentation at https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/installation (posted by @Kolban in a comment)